# How do i turn off a switch on a row and turn on another one on another row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

How do I click on a tableView row turn a switch on the row green and then when I click on next row I want to turn off the last switch and turn on the switch which on the row I clicked at? this is what i have tested this far...

```
//the switch variable is located in a custom cell
var answerSwitch = UISwitch() 
var previousSwitch = Bool()
var rowNumber = Int()  


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(indexPath.row == rowNumber && cell.answerSwitch == false) {
        cell.answerSwitch = true
    } else if(indexPath.row == rowNumber && cell.answerSwitch == true) {
       cell.answerSwitch = false
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if(previousSwitch == false) {
       rowNumber = indexPath.row
       tableView.reloadData()
       previousSwitch = true 

    } else if(previousSwitch == true) {
       tableView.reloadData
       previousSwitch = false
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to reload tableview every time.

create fun in UIViewController

```
var enabledSWitchRow: IndexPath = [0,0]

func enableSwitchFor(indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //Already answered/on switch cell
    let oldcell = tableView.cellForRow(at: enabledSWitchRow)
    oldcell.answerSwitch.isOn = false

    //selected cell
    let newcell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    newcell.answerSwitch.isOn = true

    enabledSWitchRow = indexPath
}
```

And called from didSelect delegate of UITableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.enableSwitchFor(indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

Comment: but if have split up the delegate and the tableView outlet so i have the tableView in one class and then the outlet in my viewController?

Comment: add this function in file where your tableview outlet added

Comment: ah but I'm getting that the tableView outlet has no member answerSwitch

Comment: because switch is in tableviewcell.

Comment: how do i fix that then

Comment: Upload more code of ViewController and UITableViewCell

Comment: Your answerSwitch's IBOutlet must be in UITableViewCell